# How to $rootScope.$broadcast from services in angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I $rootScope.$broadcast from services in angular.js

after $rootScope.$broadcast I would like to console.log(data) from controller but I do not see anything in the console

my code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('adf.widget.charts')
   .factory('chartService', function ($q, $rootScope){
    return {
      getSpreadsheet: function init(path){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        Tabletop.init({
          key: path,
          callback: function(data, Tabletop) {
             $rootScope.$broadcast(data)
      },
          simpleSheet: true,
          debug: true
        });
      }
    }

  })


  .controller('piechartCtrl', ['$scope', 'chartService', function($scope, chartService, urls) {
    $scope.$on('getSpreadsheet', function(data){
      console.log(data)
    });

  }]);
```

Comment: read the docs for `$broadcast`

Answer (score 1):

You `$rootScope.$broadcast` should have first parameter be the event name & there after you could pass data to that event as 2nd parameter.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('getSpreadsheet', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `$broadcast` syntax:

```
$broadcast(name, args);
```

The `name` argument represents the name of the event that should be triggered down the line of child scopes.

Example:

```
$broadcast('testEvent', 'test data');

$on('testEvent', function(arg){
   console.log(arg);   //This will log 'test data'
})
```